# ossim-extract-vertices.exe (in commandline) not working on Windows 7

Tags: mosaic, landsat-8, windows-7

ossim-extract-vertices.exe (in commandline) is not working on Windows 7. I would like to extract the image bounds from the pan-sharpened Landsat 8 image. 3 years ago it worked.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It managed, but not with old version of Ossimplanet(15.06.2009).. I downloaded Ossim-Osgeo.
The command work in commandline perfectly (27.01.2013). New Imagelinker not work :-( on WIN7.

Comment: I believe Geocell is the GUI that they are developing now. Imagelinker is no longer working in Windows.